# Fill volume algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a Box with some dimension length, width, height.

I have items with different length, width, height.

Is there an existing algorithm that can determine the best items to use to put inside the box?

Comment: Knapsack Problem in box form?

Comment: That was one of a TCO's Maraton Match problems, if you registered in TCO you can find a nice solution for it (I don't know exactly when but I think around one year ago). non of the solution is exact answer they all try to use simulated annealing and sth like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called a Bin Packing/Cutting Stock/Knapsack problem, and it is NP hard. In general you can only get an approximate solution by using heuristics, see for example

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: It's non of them. Can you explain any approximation for it?

Comment: All these algorithms help you optimize unbounded, at least in one dimension, space. What is required is to select best fit out of available items given finite box dimensions.

Comment: It probably matches none of them exactly. But they are all tightly related. E.g. a bin packing with one bin becomes another problem. In the litterature this kind of problem appears to usually be called "Three dimensional packing problem". A scholar search gives quite a lot of results http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=box+packing+problem

Comment: @Anders Forsgren, problems are different, one dimensional bin packing has a simple approximation, also it has polynomial time algorithm in many situations, I don't know about this problem but I think it's APX-Hard (means there isn't any polynomial time approximation, like Hamiltonian cycle), If is so,  problem is more difficult than bin packing, just you can give some heuristic approachs (which are not suitable in all case).

Comment: @Saeed I understand all packing/cutting problems are different and that the heuristics are different for all of them. That is why I recommend simply finding a paper with the correct heuristic for the constraints given in the problem. I doubt that the heuristics will be (or can efficiently) be presented on SO. One new and quite interesting paper is this one:
http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~sda/research/mipmodel.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This perhaps isn't actually an answer, but I believe the answer is that the problem is unanswerable. Yes, it is a version of a packing problem. 
But take a look at Erich Friedma's research in 2 dimensions: 
It seems the problem for equal sized rectangles in square is still unsolved -
Look at the complexity of some of these solutions!

http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/squinsqu/

http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/rigidrect/

(The problem is posed slightly differently, i.e. how to best arrange a certain number of items to occupy the least space, as opposed to choosing which items. But I expect your problem reduces to iterating this kind of calculation over several combinations of objects.)

and a 3-d variant which looks only very partially solved: 
http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cubincub/

Presumably your best bet is a heuristic as Anders suggests, though it almost certainly will be suboptimal for almost every problem. Interestingly, most optimal solutions appear to be highly **irregular**, so you probably wouldn't find them.

Comment: All the links are broken.

Comment: Shame. I've found the square-in-square result https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS7/html_1 but can't find the rectangles-in-squares version online.