# PHP Group row data into 2 groups based on total value

Tags: php

Below is a dataset I have

```
ID | Dept | Value

1  | 0    | 50.58

2  | 0    | 75.64

3  | 0    | 32.57

4  | 0    | 187.57

5  | 0    | 354.54
```

How would I go about splitting this down into 2 groups of Dept 1 and Dept 2 where the break down would be based on value. i.e. where value is as close as to exactly half of the total value.

In the above example IDs 1-4 would be in group 1 with a total of 346.36 and ID 5 would be in group 2 with a total of 354.54.

Comment: huh?  Half of the total value is 350.45.  So you want anything that has a value of less than this in `Dept 1` and anything else in `Dept 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very difficult question. There are lots of algorithms to do this "bin packing" solution (ie trying to equally split various sizes across various containers). This is essentially the same. Have a look at [Fill volume algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988300/fill-volume-algorithm) for more information on it.

The short answer, it's not easy, and at best you can only get an approximation to the best solution.

Comment: can you give any code examples of getting an approximation, I did not expect to get the exact answer every time as the dataset could change regularly.

Comment: I believe the link I provided for the other question has some examples. Also look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem. Basically the simplest solution is sort items by decreasing order of value, and assign them to the first department with remaining space. However in your case you don't mind overflowing slightly, so you'll have to come up with some variant of this idea.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you want it to do.

```
<?php 
// Your records stored as arrays
$records = array(
        array(1, 0, 50.58),
        array(2, 0, 75.64),
        array(3, 0, 32.57),
        array(4, 0, 187.57),        
        array(5, 0, 354.54)
);

// Blank value for total value
$total_value = 0;

// Calculate half way of total
foreach ($records AS $record)
{
    $total_value += $record[2];
}

// Get the half way point
$half_way = $total_value / 2;

// Create array for each department
$dept_1 = array();
$dept_2 = array();

// Split the records in to department
foreach ($records AS $record)
{
    if ($record[2] >= $half_way)
    {
        // Put in to department 1
        array_push($dept_2, $record);
    }
    else
    {
        // Put in to department 2
        array_push($dept_1, $record);
    }
}

// Show each departments contents
var_dump($dept_1);
var_dump($dept_2);
?>
```

It produces two arrays `$dept_1` and `$dept_2` depending on whether their values are above or below half of the total:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    float(50.58)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    float(75.64)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(3)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    float(32.57)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(4)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    float(187.57)
  }
}

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    float(354.54)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what the question asks. He wants the sum of items to assigned to each department to be approximately half the total. Your solution works in this situation (because it's 1 in one department, the rest in the other), but if you were to add another large item, it wouldn't work